# MS-Access Open a VB built query in the query window

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

**Scenario:** I am creating an advanced search form for an access database. They already have single search forms that run access queries and open in the query window.

**Problem:** I'd like to mimic this functionality but I am looking to create the query as a string within the code and then open it in a query window. Is this possible? I have searched google but didnt find anything. If its not possible are there any alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A query datasheet is a bloody awful UI. Why would you settle for something no better than that?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton, Im copying the UI from the other 3 search pages that have already been created (not my design). This is just an advanced search page that has the options of the other 3 combined, plus a little extra.

Comment: So, you're continuing the use of a poor user interface because the poor UI is already in place? Does that sound like a good long-term strategy to you?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton, A good long term strategy is getting it out of Access. This program was written by an intern in a different department who was not a coder. The entire program is macros. I would like to change the UI, etc. But I can't focus on this atm I have bigger projects to work on. Don't hate. I know its a shitty UI/solution but I cant do anything about that atm.

Comment: Your question has been answered, but I'm just pointing out that it's a band aid and doesn't really solve the fundamental problem, i.e., an ill-chosen UI design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a Form in datasheet view which looks like a query window but you need to create a form add the controls to it and then set the recordsource

e.g.

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsField As DAO.Field
Dim control As Access.TextBox

Dim frm As Form
Set frm = CreateForm()
frm.Visible = False

Dim sql As String
sql = "Select * from MSysObjects"

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)



For Each rsField In rst.Fields
    Debug.Print rsField.Name
    Set control = CreateControl(frm.Name, acTextBox, acDetail)
    With control
       .Width = 100
       .Height = 100
       .Top = 100
       .Left = 100
       .ControlSource = rsField.Name
       .Name = rsField.Name

    End With

Next rsField

Set rst = Nothing

frm.Visible = True


frm.RecordSource = sql

DoCmd.OpenForm frm.Name, acFormDS
```

There are a couple of problems with this.

1. It creates a new form each time. This means when a user closes the form they'll be asked if they want to save it. So you might want to investigate opening an existing form and modifying (clearing existing items)
2. The query is executed twice. the first time to get the fields and the second to actually show the form. Depending on what the query does this may or may not be an issue.

Honestly modifying a querydef is probably the saner way to go.